# Displaying data from csv file to fit the page

Tags: csv

I am writing the code where I need to update the data from csv file directly without mentioning any details but when I try to do that the heading of the column is not displayed properly. Is there anyway I can put - and use it.
Below is the code I am using:

```
\begin{document}        
\csvreader[%
no head,
separator=semicolon,    
generic collected table = longtblr,
generic table options = {[      
    ]{
        rowsep = 4pt,
        colsep = 2pt,
        column{even} = {c, green!10, 0.5in},
        column{odd} = {c, 0.5in},
        column{1} = {l, 2.75in},    
        row{odd} = {font = \scriptsize},
        row{even} = {font = \scriptsize},       
        %row{1} = {bg=white, 2em},
        row{1} = {font=\scriptsize\itshape},
}}, 
%table head = {\hline[0.1em, black] \raggedright\large\bfseries TABLE HEAD\\\hline[0.1em,black]},
table head = \toprule,
%               table foot = {\hline[0.1em,black]},
late after line = {\\\hline[0.15pt, black]},            
late after first line = {\\\hline[0.15pt,black]},
%   late after last line = {\\\hline[0.1em,black]},
late after last line = \\\bottomrule,   
]{data/data03.csv}{}{%
    \csvlinetotablerow%
}


\end{document}
```

[image: In the output we can see that the column headings are not getting displayed properly.]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.